# Which of the following is NOT a type of tropism?

Tags: homework, plant-anatomy

Which of the following plant movements is NOT a tropism?

1. Plant stem growing toward light
2. Plant structure growing away from light
3. Plant roots growing in response to gravity
4. Vines coiling around tree trunks
5. Leaflets folding after losing turgor pressure

Please help, I am stuck!  Thank u :)

Comment: Is there anything you can rule out definitively? Some thoughts about what you've tried will help us fill in what you're missing.

Comment: First two are ruled out for sure. I'd rule out the third, considering "Gravitropism", but some people are telling me it's the answer... So it's probably one of the last two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is #5, Leaflets folding after losing turgor pressure. This refers to a phenomenon called [plasmolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmolysis).

1 - positive [phototropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototropism), incorrect

2 - negative phototropism, incorrect

3 - [gravitropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitropism), incorrect

4 - [thigmotropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thigmotropism), incorrect